How to Integrate Tailwind CSS into Laravel Email Templates
I tried adding Tailwind CSS to my Laravel email template, but it didn't work when I sent an email. I prefer Tailwind CSS because it's easier to create responsive layouts than with regular CSS. I included tailwind link - https://cdn.tailwindcss.com
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/remixicon@3.5.0/fonts/remixicon.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>

<body class="bg-gray-100">
    <div class="mx-auto mb-4 mt-5 flex max-w-2xl justify-center rounded px-6 text-center">
        <img class="h-16 w-auto" src="/images/logos/kg_logo1.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <section class="mx-auto max-w-2xl rounded bg-white px-6 py-8 shadow-lg">
        @yield('content')

    </section>
    <div class="mx-auto my-4 max-w-2xl rounded px-6 py-5 text-center">
        <footer>

            <div class="flex w-full items-center justify-center gap-5">
                <a href="mailto:info@kisiwaagyan.com"
                    class="hover:border-#C49B42 hover:text-#C49B42 rounded-full text-[#C49B42] transition-all duration-200 hover:scale-110">
                    <i class="ri-mail-line h-16 w-auto"></i>
                </a>
                <a href="" target="_blank"
                    class="hover:border-#C49B42 hover:text-#C49B42 rounded-full text-[#C49B42] transition-all duration-200 hover:scale-110">
                    <i class="ri-youtube-line h-16 w-auto"></i>
                </a>

                <a href="" target="_blank"
                    class="hover:border-#C49B42 hover:text-#C49B42 rounded-full text-[#C49B42] transition-all duration-200 hover:scale-110">
                    <i class="ri-instagram-line h-16 w-auto"></i>
                </a>

                <a href="" target="_blank"
                    class="hover:border-#C49B42 hover:text-#C49B42 rounded-full text-[#C49B42] transition-all duration-200 hover:scale-110">
                    <i class="ri-tiktok-line h-16 w-auto"></i>
                </a>

                <a href="" target="_blank"
                    class="hover:border-#C49B42 hover:text-#C49B42 rounded-full text-[#C49B42] transition-all duration-200 hover:scale-110">
                    <i class="ri-facebook-line h-16 w-auto"></i>
                </a>

                <a href="" target="_blank"
                    class="hover:border-#C49B42 hover:text-#C49B42 rounded-full text-[#C49B42] transition-all duration-200 hover:scale-110">
                    <i class="ri-snapchat-line h-16 w-auto"></i>
                </a>

                <a href="" target="_blank"
                    class="hover:border-#C49B42 hover:text-#C49B42 rounded-full text-[#C49B42] transition-all duration-200 hover:scale-110">
                    <i class="ri-twitter-x-line h-16 w-auto"></i>
                </a>

                <a href="" target="_blank"
                    class="hover:border-#C49B42 hover:text-#C49B42 rounded-full text-[#C49B42] transition-all duration-200 hover:scale-110">
                    <i class="ri-linkedin-line h-16 w-auto"></i>
                </a>
            </div>

            <p class="mt-3 text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400" id="dateYear"></p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    <script>
        document.getElementById("dateYear").innerHTML = `© ${new Date().getFullYear()} LJSharp. All Rights Reserved.`
    </script>
</body>

</html>

How do I enable the tailwind.css? Thanks in advance.

Sorry, but you can't remotely compare Email-clients with browsers with regards to their HTML and CSS capabilities. You also can't load scripts - these will be stripped by pretty much any client. flex or grid - sorry, nope! See also https://www.caniemail.com to track multiple limitations. You should take inspiration from dedicated email-templates (yeah they still use ugly table designs most of the time since they are still required by a lot of clients)

Did you install Tailwind CSS?
If not, I recommend this one.
npm install tailwindcss
npx tailwindcss init

And then, Modify the tailwind.config.js file to include the paths of your email templates.


module.exports = {
  content: [
    './resources/views/**/*.blade.php',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}



Create a new CSS file for your email styles, e.g., email.css.


@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;



Run the Tailwind build process to generate the CSS file.
npx tailwindcss -i ./resources/css/email.css -o ./public/css/email.css --minify

Use a package like tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles to inline the CSS in your email HTML. Install the package via Composer:
composer require tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles

In your Mailable class, use the CssToInlineStyles package to inline the CSS.

use TijsVerkoyen\CssToInlineStyles\CssToInlineStyles;

public function build()
{
    $cssToInlineStyles = new CssToInlineStyles();

    $html = view('emails.your_email_template')->render();
    $css = file_get_contents(public_path('css/email.css'));

    $inlinedHtml = $cssToInlineStyles->convert($html, $css);

    return $this->html($inlinedHtml);
}



<!-- resources/views/emails/your_email_template.blade.php -->
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body class="bg-gray-100">
    <div class="mx-auto mb-4 mt-5 flex max-w-2xl justify-center rounded px-6 text-center">
        <img class="h-16 w-auto" src="{{ asset('images/logos/kg_logo1.png') }}" alt="">
    </div>
    <section class="mx-auto max-w-2xl rounded bg-white px-6 py-8 shadow-lg">
        @yield('content')
    </section>
    <div class="mx-auto my-4 max-w-2xl rounded px-6 py-5 text-center">
        <footer>
            <div class="flex w-full items-center justify-center gap-5">
                <a href="mailto:info@kisiwaagyan.com" class="hover:border-#C49B42 hover:text-#C49B42 rounded-full text-[#C49B42] transition-all duration-200 hover:scale-110">
                    <i class="ri-mail-line h-16 w-auto"></i>
                </a>
                <!-- Add other social icons similarly -->
            </div>
            <p class="mt-3 text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400" id="dateYear"></p>
        </footer>
    </div>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("dateYear").innerHTML = `© ${new Date().getFullYear()} LJSharp. All Rights Reserved.`
    </script>
</body>
</html>




Wow! Great. I followed this tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fClNAhCTjGw and it works great. Thanks for the help :)

It's my pleasure
